# Is a script inside a node executed indefinitely? (ROS Question)

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I couldn't find any exclusive answer to my question anywhere, other than chatgpt, but you can't really trust that. I was wondering, does a node loop the script inside? I am following the [ROS2 Tutorials](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) and when you write a simple publisher code, there is no loop, neither while nor for loop. But when you run the code in terminal with "ros2 run ..." it starts saying, "Hello world 1, Hello world 2 ...". So, I am guessing ROS executes this code over and over again. If it is correct a have some other questions:

1. As far as I can see there is no delay function. So, is the loop as fast as your pc can manage?
2. If there is service between two nodes, are they looped anyway? Or in this case, the code is executed only when service requests it to?

I seached it on google, got nothing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to understand the concept better by reading the tutorials more carefully. But here is the high level concept for the subscriber / publisher case:

When you spin the node, it sort of becomes activated, meaning it will be able to listen to triggers. When running the publisher node, you - among other things - initialise the timer. The timer has a callback function, which gets triggered every 0.5 seconds. Within this callback function, the publisher publishes the message.

On the subscriber side, you can find another callback function. This functions gets called whenever a message of the 'topic' topic arrives.

So as you can see, ros doesn't "loop" the nodes, they rather respond to actions. The callback functions play an important role here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really is helpful. I try to read them as careful as I am able, but sometimes I miss some nuances